# OpenSSL temporary error during connection to RDS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, openssl, amazon-rds

There is the project on Laravel, which has DB on Amazon RDS. It works well, but sometimes I found such kind of error in the logs:

> ErrorException: PDO::prepare(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
> OpenSSL Error messages: error:0407008A:rsa
> routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding
> error:04067072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:padding check
> failed in

/var/www/html/backend/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:61

I googled that problem but can't found the solution. Can someone had the same and know how to solve it?

**UPD**
configuration

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql_ssl
DB_HOST=rds-url
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=dbusername
DB_PASSWORD=dbpassword
AMAZON_CERT_PATH=path/to/pemfile

'mysql_ssl' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => base_path(env('AMAZON_CERT_PATH', ''))
    ]
],
```

**UPD**

I've got one more error message:

> PDO::prepare(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
> messages: error:04067084:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:data too
> large for modulus

The issue is temporary, it appears on different SQL requests. I don't have any idea the issue became from.

Comment: Might be helpful to provide details on the way you're connecting i.e. configuration (without actual credentials or endpoints of course)